# How does Claire travel through the standing stones in Outlander?

Tags: time-travel, adaptation-comparison, outlander-universe

In *Outlander* the book by Diana Gabaldon, I recall (although it has been several years) Claire falling into the stones and accidentally back in time. In the new television adaptation, however, the stones make a loud noise and she touches them, then falling through time.

I don't understand how either method of time travel works, so to speak, but am more interested in the universe of the books, and I don't believe it has been properly explained in the television series yet.

How does one travel through the stones? Is it in the act of falling, something to do with the druid ceremony, moon cycle, etc?

Comment: I'm reading the book right now, and she hears the stones "screaming" which might be why they added the loud noise in the show.

Answer (score 4):

In the books, the "time gate" or whatever you want to call it, is most powerful around the old Sun or Fire Feast days. Samhain (Nov. 1) is one of them and would have been roughly when Claire went through the stones. Also, she described a loud buzzing sound, like a large hornets nest, the closer she came to the cleft stone. When she touched it she heard a loud buzzing and rock grinding sound. She also said that she could feel people screaming inside it. She passes out and when she wakes she is outside the circle. The further into the series you go, the more she and, yes, other time travellers, guess about the portals. There is more than one portal, most of them marked by small henges but not all. The portals will still work at other times of the year, but the person going through is less likely to survive the trip.

Answer (score 4):

Claire's going through the stones was not accidental, but fated.

Spoiler alert for anyone who hasn't yet read through Dragonfly in Amber…  Don't read this post if you don't want to know!

My understanding of time-travel in the Outlander series is that time moves forward, but now and then, a “loop” comes about and is fated to occur.  For example, Mary Hawkins was destined to remain virginal until married to a French nobleman.  However, Mary was working late at the Paris hospital only because Claire was there, and so, became raped and forced down another path toward Alex Randall.  Likewise, because of Claire being at the manor where Mary was staying, Mary did not marry Mr. Isaacson.  Because of Claire’s presence in the 18th century, Mary Hawkins would then give birth to Frank’s ancestor, and seal Claire’s destiny in the 20th century.

In other words, if Claire had not gone back in time, Frank would not have existed.  If Geillis Duncan had not gone back in time, the money she stole to supporting the 1745/46 rising would not have been available.  Without the defeat of the Scots in 1746, Geillis Duncan would have had no reason to travel to the 18th century to try to do something toward the Scots’ success.  Her efforts failed in the desired result.  History occurred as it was meant to happen.  Time works on a loop – certain individuals are destined to go back in time, in order for the fated future to happen.

Notice that Claire’s time travel did not in fact change history, try as she might.  The Battle of Culloden still happens with its aftermath.  She cannot stop what is fated to occur, and she is actually a part having fate fulfilled.  If she really wanted to stop Charles and change history, why not just slip him some cyanide?  But she does not.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the actual mechanics of the stones' time travel is totally irrelevant to the story. That is - the author was not concerned about the HOW of the time travel; she just waved her hands to create a situation where people could be moved in time and then built a story on that fish-out-of-water situation (complete with lots of sexy sex!).

The TV show's loud noise, etc, is purely for dramatic effect to show to the viewer that something has happened.

Comment: Actually, the loud noise comes straight from the books and is what allows others, such as Jamie, to "sense" that there is something to Claire's story since he can hear a noise and feel a vibration in the air.

Comment: To Jamie, the stones are silent. Only those who can travel through the stones can hear them. But the sound draws them in, puts them in sort of a trance. For Jamie, the trance is the evidence that something is going on that he does not "ken."